# How do I perform an Ajax Modal Popup based on a "data-" property?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Basically, I have a dynamically created list and I have no idea in advance how many items there will be.

I need each one to launch a slightly different Ajax function on clicking.

I am currently using JQM for the modal boxes (happy to switch if someone knows something better).

The following code works fine for making all `.ajaxpopup` items launch the same page :

```
  $().ready(function () {
            $('#dialog').jqm({ ajax: "/QuestionManager/AjaxPopup/1", trigger: ".ajaxpopup" });

            $(".ajaxpopup").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

However, I need each item to launch a different page (1/2... I don't know the ID in advance).

I really like Adam's answer about adding a `data-itemid` tag to the element, but, I just can't seem to actually make this work.

I do not know if this is a JQM limitation or due to the way it is initiated.

The closest I have come is:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function () {
        var itemId = $(this).data("itemid");

        $('#dialog').jqm({ ajax: "/QuestionManager/AjaxPopup/"+itemId, trigger: ".ajaxpopup" });
    });
```

I have also replaced the dialog line with `alert(itemId)`, which is giving the correct result, so, I know I am along the right path - I just can't seem to get this done!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wire dyanmically added content to respond to events via jQuery's `live` and `on` functions.

So if I'm understanding your particular case, you want those text nodes, when clicked, to launch a jqm modal?  And you want your model's itemId to be a part of it?

First, add the itemId to your text via a data attribute:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Routines)
{
    <text data-itemid='@item.itemId'></text>
} //(sorry if the razor syntax is off a bit - that's not my expertise
```

And then:

```
$(document).on("click", "text", function() { 
    var itemId = $(this).data("itemid");
    var textnodeText = $(this).text();
    $('#dialog').jqm({ ajax: "/QuestionManager/_AjaxCreateQuestionInitial/" + textnodeText, 
                       trigger: itemId });
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, if you have this html:

```
<a href="/test/AddData" data-itemid="1">Add Data</a>
```

You can handle the click event like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    var itemId = $(this).data("itemid");
    //now run your ajax call
});
```

Comment: As per in the example, I need to create an Ajax model box that launches a page which has the ID in it... I don't suppose you can give an example that actually does this as I have been trying for the past hour without luck :(

Comment: @WilliamHilsum - I think I understand your requirements now - does my last edit match what you're looking for?

Comment: It looks good... I am happy as I really wanted to learn from this!... I am trying to implement now. +1 for thanks and will mark as answer if it works!

Comment: @WilliamHilsum - sweet.  Good luck!

Comment: @WilliamHilsum - btw, that +1 was my 20th upvote in the closing seconds of "yesterday" (GMT), so thanks for capping me :-D

Comment: I really like the idea of using the data-itemID approach, however, I just can't get the jquery code to work. I am guessing the "text" part is to get the "Text" link above, however, (if you are interested) that is not what/how MVC works.... The actual code I used was `@Html.ActionLink("Add Data", "AddData", new { id = item.ID }, new { data_itemid = item.ID })` ... This created the following (standard) HTML - `<a href="/test/AddData" data-itemid="1">Add Data</a>` ... I have tried dropping the "text" and modifying, but, I am not having much luck with your code.

Comment: Anyway... I have been trying for the past hour (or more) to get this working and I need to lie down! Happy to get you to the 20th vote! ... If you can help later, it will be appreciated! - this approach is certainly much better than I was trying, and, I should (hopefully) be able to lob all this in to a .JS file rather than go down the bad route I was trying! Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamHilsum - I put some new code up there, based on your comment.  Hopefully that will take you closer.

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate your help, and I think I know what is going on here, the last update got me closer... Trigger: needs to be an ID or class, so, it is not attaching. Anyway, falling asleep at my keyboard - I have an idea on how to fix this and will try in the morning. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ok... I am awake now! I didn't need the textnodeText part as I actually wanted the link to go to the itemId, but, I see what you have done and it is cool... however, I still can't get this to work, but, I think this is just a limitation of JQM, and, I am looking for alternate modal/ajax boxes I can use in the project. If you can help any more, please do, but, thanks for the help so far - I really like this approach.

Comment: If you are there, I have been trying all day without much luck to get this working! I don't suppose you are free/can come to chat :( http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript Sorry about this! Just so desperate to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create an JsonResult providing Action on your Contoller, that would provide list of items you need? Once that is in place I would iterate over the JSON array and prodce the boxes.

assuming your data would be (an example - this needs to be produced by your controller)

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 1, "Name": "A"}, 
 {"Id": 2, "Name": "B"}, 
 {"Id": 3, "Name": "C"}
];
```

Your javascript (jquery) loop to handle your boxes would be

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    //replace with your dialog code 
    alert(data[i].Id+" "+data[i].Name);
});​
```